# VBA: import joined SAP data to Excel via RFC

Tags: excel, vba, import, sap-erp, saprfc

I'm currently working on a project and I'm trying to import production data from SAP ERP using VBA to automate the process. However the database that I want to import is made up of multiple tables like `MARA` and `MARC`. I have gotten to the point where I can import a single table but how can I join multiple tables together without importing them one by one and then doing the calculations afterwards?

Regards and thanks in advance.

EDIT (from OP comment): "I don't want to do anything manually but providing the login credentials. Furthermore I need to bring the data that I import into a specific format for which I was planning to use Excel. Are there any other options to import data from SAP ERP using VBA while joining the data from different tables? At the moment I am using `RFC_READ_TABLE` and it seemed to work fine but if what you're saying is true I'll have to look for a different way because I assume that just importing every single table and then joining them afterwards with Excel or Access is nonsense."

Answer (score 1):

Sadly RFC Read Table can only pull from one table at a time. (*assuming this is the method you are currently using in VB*A)

SQ01 Queries would let you Join Multiple Tables At once. But you would then Have to Manually Export the data, If you Cant do all your Calculations Within the Query.

SAP Has a reporting system with BEx Analyzer that may be able to Make the Joins if you have this software at your disposial

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
I don't want to do anything manually but providing the login credentials. Furthermore I need to bring the data that I import into a specific format for which I was planning to use Excel. Are there any other options to import data from SAP using VBA while joining the data from different tables?
At the moment I am usin RFC Read Table and it seemed to work fine but if what you're saying is true I'll have to look for a different way because I assume that just importing every single table and then joining them afterwards with Excel or Access is nonsense.